# Want to restore the cart with the order id and details in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I got struck with this question is there is any way through which I will restore the cart with the help of order details and order id.I want to do same as reorder function in Prestashop.In Magento there is a simple code to restore the cart with the help of last order id like this:

```
 if ($lastQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId()) {
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($lastQuoteId);
            $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
        }
```

If something like this work on Prestashop.It would be a great help for me.
Please give me your valuable suggestions.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/front/ParentOrderController.php#L80) code on how prestashop recreates a cart from order id.

Comment: Thanks, Drot, I got my answer from the code you have mentioned in your comments.I am updating it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with the Help of TheDrot.Thanks for the reference.

```
$order = new Order(Order::getOrderByCartId($id_cart));
if ($order) {
        $oldCart = new Cart($id_cart);
        $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
        if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
        } elseif (!$duplication['success']) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
        } else {
            $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
            $context = $this->context;
            $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
            CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
            $this->context->cookie->write();
            if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
            }
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
        }
    }
```